# ElementaryOS Won't boot after normal installation from live USB

Tags: system-installation, boot, grub, uefi

I've installed ElementaryOS, and it won't boot.

It shows me the ElementaryOS Logo, but then it changes to a terminal with the cursor blinking.

There is no text in the terminal whatsoever.

Please help quickly, as I would like to use ElementaryOS.

I tried using boot-repair, didn't help either :(

If it's helpful, I had Ubuntu 20.04 on it before, and I deleted the boot partition in the installation process of ElementaryOS.(I wiped the entire Drive in the Installation menu)

Secureboot is disabled, it is set to UEFI mode.

Comment: There is a boot partition(Fat32)

Answer (score 0):

May I know if you are using this in a PC or laptop? If laptop, are you plugged in or not. I can't remember which distro but once I had this issue if I am not plugged in.